# How to acquire Windows 10 Host IP from an ubuntu HyperV Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a server running on my windows machine and a hyper-v ubuntu VM
I am trying to test the frontend from my VM but I want to make requests to windows 10
host, how can I get the host's IP?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Wired Connected` -> `Wired Settings` and just copy the DNS IP